# navTo only working for one page

Tags: sapui5

I have a the following function in my controller file:

```
handleNavTo : function (oEvent){
        var page = oEvent.getSource().data("navToPage");
        var router = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);
        router.navTo(page);
    }
```

So I don't have to write out a new function for each link, I'm using a data attribute in an XML view to pass in the page I want to navigate to, like this:

```
<StandardTile 
    title="{i18n>tileEmployees}" 
     press="handleNavTo" 
     data:navToPage="employees"
     icon="sap-icon://employee"/>
 <StandardTile 
     title="{i18n>tileProducts}" 
     press="handleNavTo" 
     data:navToPage="products" 
     icon="sap-icon://product"/>
```

I have the routing configured in a manifest.json file:

```
"routing": {
  "config": {
    "routerClass": "sap.m.routing.Router",
    "viewType": "XML",
    "viewPath": "testApp.view",
    "controlId": "app",
    "controlAggregation": "pages",
    "transition": "slide",
    "bypassed": {
      "target": "notFound"
    }
  },
  "routes": [
    {
      "pattern": "",
      "name": "appHome",
      "target": "home"
    },
    {
      "pattern": "products",
      "name:": "products",
      "target": "products"
    },
    {
      "pattern": "employees",
      "name": "employees",
      "target": "employees"
    }
  ],
  "targets": {
    "home": {
      "viewName": "Home",
      "viewLevel": 1
    },
    "notFound": {
      "viewName": "NotFound",
      "transition": "flip"
    },
    "products": {
      "viewPath": "testApp.view.products",
      "viewName": "ProductsSplitView",
      "viewType": "JS",
      "viewLevel": 2
    },
    "employees": {
      "viewPath": "testApp.view.employees",
      "viewName": "EmployeesSplitView",
      "viewType": "JS",
      "viewLevel": 2
    }
  }
```

My problem is that clicking on the tiles only works for the Employees page. I know the routing is configured correctly for the products page as I can type in the url in the address bar and it brings up the page: `mydomain.com/#/products`.

I get no errors, it just seems to silently fail. the data attribute value is being called correctly, if I `console.log(page)` in the controller function I get the correct value, so this has be stumped.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i would guess that it does not find the route by name because you have a typo in the route config: `"name:": "products",` should be `"name": "products",`

Comment: Oh dear, how embarrassing! That was the problen, I've looked over that code for errors several times, sometimes just needs a second pair of eyes I guess. Thanks very much.